# SQL- return a difference of number in a column in a table grouped by year (ORACLE)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have two table as below:

Asset Table:

```
assetnum | depid
----------------
1        | eng
2        | ap
3        | cao
.        | .
.        | .
.        | .
```

AND

Meterreading Table:

```
assetnum | meterreading_date | reading
---------------------------------------
1        | 4/7/2017          |  50000
2        | 3/5/17            |  30000
3        | 1/15/17           |  10000
.        | .                 |  .
.        | .                 |  .
.        | .                 |  .
```

I am struggleing to do a join and to get a yearly usage of each asset. In other words I would like to get
the assetnum, depid, (the last reading at the last date recorded in that year - the first reading at the first date recorded in that year) as Usage grouped by year.

for instance in the case above I will have the output as

```
assetnum | depid  | usage
-------------------------
 1       |  eng   |   40000  (50000-10000)
 .       |   .    |   .
 .       |   .    |   .
 .       |   .    |   .
```

Comment: What would you be joining on?  The assetnum? I am asking because based on depid it seems that that rows with assetnum 1 and 3 are for different values. Yet, in the example output you grouped them together... If you just want to get the difference between "oldest"-"newest" row from meterreading table, you do not need to join. Last question: I guess that for the meterreading table the key consists of assetnum and meterreading_date (there will not be two assetnums for same date)- is that right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tweeking Gordon's response...  just extract the year from the date and then group by it eliminating the where.

```
SELECT mr.assetnum
     , a.depid
     , max(usage) - min(usage) as usage
     , to_char(meterreading_date,'YYYY') as Year
FROM Meterreading mr 
INNER join Asset a
  on mr.assetnum = a.assetnum
GROUP BY  mr.assetnum, a.depid, to_char(meterreading_date,'YYYY')
```

Or... using extract vs to_char...

```
SELECT mr.assetnum
     , a.depid
     , max(usage) - min(usage) as usage
     , extract(year from meterreading_date) as Year
FROM Meterreading mr 
INNER join Asset a
  on mr.assetnum = a.assetnum
GROUP BY  mr.assetnum, a.depid, extract(year from meterreading_date)
```

in both cases this gets the MIN and max Usage per year and subtracts the min from the max.  it's not Date driven, rather usage/year driven.  If you for some reason had a low reading later in the year than the high... it may not return the desired results...  to truly be date driven we would need to get the min/max dates find the usage for those and go from there.

Example if reading were:

```
assetnum | meterreading_date | reading
---------------------------------------
1        | 7/5/2017          |  70000
1        | 6/1/2017          |  10000
1        | 5/7/2017          |  60000
1        | 4/7/2017          |  50000
1        | 3/5/17            |  30000
1        | 1/15/17           |  20000
```

Then the usage for 2017 for assetnum 1 would be 70000-10000 or 60000; but maybe you wanted 70000-20000=50000...

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just want a `join` and `group by`:

```
select mr.assetnum, a.depid,
       (max(usage) - min(usage)) as usage
from Meterreading mr join
     Asset a
     on mr.assetnum = a.assetnum
where meterreading_date >= date '2017-01-01 and
      meterreading_date < '2018-01-01'  -- unnecessary for the current year
group by mr.assetnum, a.depid;
```

Comment: Or you could strip out the year from date and display and group by it and avoid the where logic.

Comment: I have dates from 2005 all the way to now and wanted to group by year.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer grouped by year:

```
SELECT reading.*, max_reading-min_reading used, depid
FROM 
  ( SELECT TRUNC(meterreading_date,'yyyy') meterreading_date, assetnum, MIN(reading) min_reading, MAX(reading) max_reading
    FROM METERREADING
    GROUP BY TRUNC(meterreading_date,'yyyy'), assetnum
  ) reading
    JOIN
  asset ON asset.assetnum=reading.assetnum
```